# MAD detection error

Tags: r, median, outliers

I am using code I borrowed *https://rpubs.com/hauselin/outliersDetect* to calculate Median Absolute Deviation to detect outliers and replace with NA.

See below:

```
outliersMAD <- function(data, MADCutOff = 2.5, replace = NA, values = FALSE,     
  bConstant = 1.4826, digits = 2) {
  #compute number of absolute MADs away for each value
  #formula: abs( ( x - median(x) ) )/ mad(x)
  absMADAway <- abs((data - median(data, na.rm = TRUE))/mad(data, constant =   
  bConstant, na.rm = TRUE))
  #subset data that has absMADAway greater than the MADCutOff and replace them 
  with replace
  #can also replace values other than replace
  data[absMADAway > MADCutOff] <- replace

  if (values == TRUE) { 
     return(round(absMADAway, digits)) #if values == TRUE, return number of   
     mads for each value
  } else {
     return(round(data, digits)) #otherwise, return values with outliers   
     replaced
  }
}
```

I would like to apply this to columns 4 - 52 of my data as follows:

```
data[,4:52] <- outliersMAD(data[4:52])
```

However I receive the error 'need numeric data'

This code does work, however, if I use something like:

```
outliersMAD(data$columnofinterest)
```

Not sure how best to move forward, new to R, would appreciate any help!

Comment: daat[4:52] is a list, try using `lapply(data[4:52], outliersMAD)`, or `plyr:colwise`

Comment: Beautiful, thanks!

Comment: or `apply(data[,4:52], 2, outliersMAD)`